# Why am I asked for default's keyring at startup?

Tags: login, password

I'm prompted for default's keyring at every boot since 11.10 upgrade, even though I don't see any application I have needing at startup (I have no wifi, and disabled gwibber-service)
How can I know which application is requesting it ? How can I disable it ?
I can't even move any window until I enter the password, and sometimes entering the password even crashes X (bug reported here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/882955)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug, see the above link to the bug report. There is no fix availabe yet, just a work around (from the bug report)

> This bug only seems to occur when I type the keyring's password really fast at login.
>
> It looks like I've found a fix : waiting for a few seconds before entering it.